# Vector CANoe - How do you build a .NET tests node with multiple C# files?

Tags: c#, .net, testing, canoe

**Objectives**
I want to use the Vector CANoe C# (.NET) scripting capability.
More specifically, I want to reduce my .NET test nodes' complexity by building some core utility classes.

For example, instead of having this

```
// With the Vector API directly
IVT2516Channel M4_Ch9 = vts.GetChannel("M4_Ch9");
M4_Ch9.DigitalOutput.Value = true;
```

An object could do this:

```
// With an Object that abstract the Vector API
MyECU ecu = utilities.MyECU();
ecu.OpenContactor(True);
```

To achieve this, my plan was to build a `utilities.cs` file that every .NET tests module would use.
The idea is roughly this:

```
+---------------------------+
| CANoe Test environment    |
|                           |
|   +--------+ +--------+   |
|   |  .NET  | |  .NET  |   |
|   |  test  | |  test  |   |
|   | module | | module |   |
|   +--------+ +--------+   |
|        |         |        |
+--------|---------|--------+
         |         |
+--------v---------v--------+
|                           |
|    CORE UTILITIES (C#)    |
|                           |
+---------------------------+
             |
+------------v--------------+
|                           |
|       VECTOR Modules      |
|                           |
+---------------------------+
```

**Problem**
I can't get the compiler happy.
I always get error CS0246.
In the CANoe console:

```
System  Testmodule 'Test 1': Compilation of tests_wakeup.cs' failed with error(s)
System  tests_wakeup.cs(17,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'utilities' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

When using the Visual studio, my solution build without problems.

**Question**
How do you build a .NET tests node with multiple C# files?

Comment: What did you configure as your testmodule? A (c sharp) source file or an assembly?

Comment: @M.Spiller I'm not very familiar with the c# assembly process, so a tried everything I could think of: as a c# project, a .cs source file and a .dll file. They all produce the same kind of error and they all built without error in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you selected the file `utilities.cs` in the CANoe test configuration.

With that setting, CANoe will only compile a single file, even if you can compile the whole project in Visual Studio.

However, CANoe does not only support `.cs` files but also `.dll` and `.sln` files.

Knowing this, you can simply change your configuration to use the solution file of the Visual Studio project or the output DLL file.

---

<sup>Note: I had the same problem and I found this post while looking for a solution.</sup>

Comment: This solved my issue. For documentation purposes: In the CANoe tests setup window, you can add a `.NET tests module`. This tests module can as mentioned by @dan1st, you can add a visual studio  `.sln` files. This will force CANoe to compile your multiple file solutions. Thanks again Sir/Madam.

Comment: As I said, I had the same issue :)